# Get current file name on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a set of files in a Rails project and I need to get the current file name. I'm using the following:

```
<%= __FILE__ %>
```

But it is outputting the full file path:

```
/Users/[myuser]/Documents/Development/welcome.html.erb
```

I just need the file name:

```
welcome
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shortname = File.basename(__FILE__, ".html.erb")
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the filename only, you can use [File#basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-basename) method:

```
File.basename(__FILE__, '.html.erb') 
# => welcome
```

or,

```
File.basename(__FILE__, '.*') 
# => welcome
```

So, your code becomes:

```
<%= File.basename(__FILE__, '.html.erb') %>
```

Comment: How about remove the extension of the file? and leave just the file name?

Comment: Yes, just the file name

Comment: @GEspinha please look at my updated answer and let me know if you have any other question. Thanks.